# Mutually Dependent Function Declarations in Functions

Tags: function, scope, d, function-calls

Is it possible to have two or more outer function-scoped functions that have mutual call dependencies on each other?

I'm asking because

```
void main(string args[]) {
    int x = 42;
    void a() {
        // do something with x
        b();
    }
    void b() {
        // do something with x
        a();
    }
}
```

errors in DMD as

```
/home/per/Work/justd/t_funs.d(5): Error: undefined identifier b
```

If not is this an unresolved issue or a feature?

Comment: by declaring them outside main

Comment: Sometimes you want scoped functions to access scoped data (in main in this case). So there's no way achieve this in D? It seems strange that the compiler cannot do this. Maybe its related to D being a single pass language I guess. I can live without it. I just have to do a bit more refactoring in my project.

Comment: it's not single pass, but you can declare a function delegate before a and assign b to it I think

Comment: @ratchetfreak don't forget to type that up as an answer too. That's the only way to do this (except for making it a struct or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can declare the delegate `b` before a and then assign `b`

```
void main(string args[]) {
    int x = 42;
    void delegate() b;
    void a() {
        // do something with x
        b();
    }
    b = delegate void () {
        // do something with x
        a();
    };
}
```

it'll require a refactor but not as bad as throwing it all in structs

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you could. Then you could do:

```
void main(string args[]) {
    void a() {
        b();
    }
    a();
    int x = 42;
    void b() {
        // do something with x
        a();
    }
}
```

And viola - you use `x` before declaring it.

There are workarounds to that - like ratchet freak said you could use a delegate, but you could also use a struct:

```
void main(){
    int x=5;
    struct S{
        void a(){
            writefln("in a, x=%d",x);
            --x;
            if(0<x){
                b();
            }
        }
        void b(){
            writefln("in b, x=%d",x);
            --x;
            if(0<x){
                a();
            }
        }
    }
    S().a();
}
```

Notice that both solutions prevent using `x` before it's declaration. If you use a delegate you can't call it before you assign a function to it, which you can only do after you declare the other function, which happens after you declare `x`. If you use a struct you can't declare `x` either before of in the struct - but you can only call the functions after the struct is declared - which also means after `x` is declared.

Answer (score 2):

That's by design: "Unlike module level declarations, declarations within function scope are processed in order." (http://dlang.org/function.html#variadicnested)

Don't know the rationale though.

Comment: Idan Arye's answer gives a good explanation. If you access the variable before it is declared, it could be any value. Even though the forward access could perhaps be handled, since the initializer could be a variable, and thus only known at runtime, accessing it wold have undefined behavior (at best)